# PowerShell Test If a Filename From a List Exists Somewhere In a Directory and Export Missing

Tags: powershell, compare, powershell-2.0, export-to-csv

I've researched this and haven't been able to come up with a solid solution. Basically, I have a separate hard drive containing thousands of music files. I have a CSV list with the names of all the files that should be in the hard drive. Example:

[My List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GQ7N.png)

I want to be able to test if each of the files on my list exist in the hard drive, and if not, export it to a separate "missing files" list. The thing is each of the files in the hard drive exist under multiple folders.

As my script is now, I am trying to test if the path exists by using join-path. Here is my code right now - it's returning all of the files in the directory instead of just the missing files:

```
$documents = 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\ScriptTest'
$CSVexport = 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\ScriptTest\TestResults.csv'

$obj = @()
    Write-host "`n_____Results____`n" #Write the results and export to a CSV file
    $NewCsv = Import-CSV -Path 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\ScriptTest\Test.csv' |
        Select-Object ID,'File Path' |  
            ForEach-Object {
                if (!(Test-Path (Join-Path $documents $_.'File Path'))){
                    write-host "`n$($_.'File Path') is missing from the folder.`n"
                    $ObjectProperties = @{
                        ID = $_.ID
                        'File Path' = $_.'File Path'
                    }
                $obj += New-Object PSObject -Property $ObjectProperties
                }
            }
            $obj | export-csv $CSVexport -NoTypeInformation
```

How do I account for the sub-directories that vary with each file?

---

### **Edit - Resolved**

```
$myFolder = 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\ScriptTest'
$CSVexport = 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\ScriptTest\Results.csv'
$csvPath = 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\ScriptTest\Test.csv'

$FileList = Get-ChildItem $myFolder -Recurse *.wav | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -Unique
Import-CSV -Path $csvPath | 
    Where-Object {$FileList -notcontains $_.'File Path'} |
    export-csv $CSVexport -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could generate a list of filenames from the recursed folders, then check if the file is in that list.

```
$documents = 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\ScriptTest'
$CSVexport = 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\ScriptTest\TestResults.csv'

$FileList = Get-ChildItem $documents -Recurse |
    Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -Unique
Import-CSV -Path 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\ScriptTest\Test.csv' | 
    Where-Object {$FileList -notcontains $_.File} |
    Export-CSV $CSVexport -NoTypeInformation
```

Edit: Answer updated to work with PowerShell 2.0 with suggestions from Bruce Payette and mklement0

Comment: Getting these errors: "You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator."
"Unexpected token 'notin' in expression or statement."
"Unexpected token 'FileList' in expression or statement."

Comment: The `-in` and `-notin` operators were introduced in PowerShell V3. With PowerShell V2, you have to use the `-notcontains` operator as in `$FileList -notcontains $_.File`

Comment: @BrucePayette Thanks, I am using V2 so some of those operators don't work. Is there anything I can use in place of -file?

Comment: @jl93: `Get-ChildItem $documents -Recurse -File` -> `Get-ChildItem $documents -Recurse | Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer }`

Comment: @jl93 I missed the PowerShell 2.0 tag. Answer updated with the suggestions from Bruce Payette and mklement0.